# Php date time add hours

Tags: php, datetime, time

Okay I have a iOS app that relays some information to a php script and I have a slider inside of my application that asks for how many hours to delay from the current time

So here is my code in php

```
<?php
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$TimeDelay = 36;
$NewTime = $date + 36;
?>
```

So basically what I want is where the date is changed to add 36 hours to it the time delay can range from 1 to 48 being 1 hour up to 48 hours.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there you could use mktime

```
<?php
$hours = 36;
$NewTime = mktime(date('H')+$hours,date('i'),date('s'),date('n'),date('j'),date('Y'));
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$NewTime);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use PHP's [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$NewTime = strtotime("+{$TimeDelay} hours");
```